# How to add a default value for a column if it is null OR blank? i.e. a whitespace like ''

Tags: sql-server

I added a constraint for one of my columns, the idea being, if it is blank or `null`, the default value will be unknown.

```
ALTER TABLE Persons
ADD CONSTRAINT df_City
DEFAULT 'Unknown' FOR City;
```

I uploaded some samples, and the constraint works with `null`, but not with `''`.

How can I make it work with `''`?

SQL Server 14.0.1000.169

Comment: *"the constraint works with `null`, but not with `''`"*.Your understanding is flawed here, Default constraints don't "work" with `NULL` or `''`, they are only used if you *omit* the column from the `INSERT`, which is *not* the same as (explicitly) supplying the value `NULL`. Notice in this [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=28a85327abaeee0eff1e92eff390357a) that the row where `I` has a value of `2` that the column `S` has the value `NULL` *not* the `DEFAULT` (`'abc'`).

Comment: Without knowing enough about your environment, I would suggest that perhaps what you should be doing is making your column `NOT NULL` and have a check constraint that ensures the `LEN` of the value is `> 0`. Then people *can't* `INSERT` the values `NULL` or `''` into it.

Comment: Side note: SQL Server 14.0.1000.169 is SQL Server 2017 **RTM**. That build was released on 2017-10-02; over 4 years ago. Why haven't you applied a single update to your SQL Server instance in the last ~54 months? There are multiple known (and fixed) security fixes that have been released since October 2017.

Comment: Have you tried adding an `IF` Statement?